# Lazarus pointer type in C#

Tags: c#, lazarus, freepascal

I am trying to convert a lazarus project to c#. It's been good so far but i have a problem now.

There is a code like this:

```
    xActor = record
    Id: integer;
    Value: integer;
    Name: ansistring;
    Height: integer;
    Gender : Boolean;
    Position : byte;
  end;
```

I created this in c# as a struct. However, after this code i saw something like this

```
PxActor = ^xActor;
```

I've researched a bit and found out that this means create a type that includes xActor's pointers i may be wrong tho.

Then i saw a more interesting record in the code

```
    yActor = packed record 
    Actor: array [1..9] of PxActor;
  end;
```

at this point i have no idea how to convert these to c# since i have no idea what `PxActor = ^xActor;` means.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "create a type that includes xActor's pointers" - more precisely expressed, it means "create a type `PxActor`; variables of type `PxActor` are pointers to records of type `xActor`."

Comment: You should look into declaring it as a class instead of as a struct. `^xActor` means "pointer to xActor".

Comment: You can read it as `PxActor` type is a pointer to the `xActor` structure. And inside the `yActor` record is the `Actor` array of such pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# has two different kinds of an object - a reference-type, and a value-type.

The code you have is mixing the two (very common in C/Pascal), because you have a C# value-type (the `struct` xActor) and a reference-type referring to the same type (the pointer `PxActor`), which isn't *quite* possible in C#.

However, there are ways to emulate similar behaviour. But first, you have to think about the logical way this is supposed to work. Maybe this is just a performance tweak (e.g. the array of `PxActor` is used instead of `xActor` because you want to save up on the extra memory from having the whole `xActor` structure there). Perhaps it's rather that you want to have the same value available from multiple places, and mutable.

Both cases can usually be solved by simply making `xActor` a `class` - in C#, that means that it will always be a reference type (not something that makes sense in C/Pascal, but the predominant object in C# and similar languages). However, you need to manually check every place where anything of type `xActor` or `PxActor` is used, and make sure the value/reference semantics are still the same. This can lead to some hard to find bugs, depending on the original code.

Another option is to create a wrapper class. So you'll keep your `struct xActor`, but you'll also create a `class PxActor`, which will have a single `xActor` field. This is not an exact analogue of Pascal's pointers, but if you're careful, it can be used in a similar way. The main difference is that you can't capture a pointer to an existing value somewhere - you can only create a new `PxActor`, with it's own *copy* of `xActor`. Anyone accessing the `PxActor` instance will also be working with the same `xActor` instance, but anytime you store the `xActor` itself, it's a new copy. But in the simplest case, you can replace manual allocations of `xActor` and a subsequent `@` into `new PxActor()`, and any `variable^.Gender` access to `variable.ActorField.Gender`.

Just during the refactoring itself, it would also be possible to use C#'s pointers. They are a bit limited compared to C/Pascal's, but they might work for your cases. Except for that `string` value. However, pointers have lots of costs, so you don't want to use them unless they are a good idea, and this isn't that case :)

In other words, it's usually a bad idea to do a 1:1 translation from Pascal to C#. You need to figure out what the semantics behind all the stuff is. Finding *all* the usages of a given type is going to be a huge chore. Translating line-by-line can easily paint you into a corner. C# is a very safe language, and CLR is very good at making sure everyone can talk with each other, but this also means a few differences in stuff like value/reference passing and similar. Now, IIRC, Pascal has value semantics by default, so using `struct` and similar should mostly work well in C# as well. You'll have to analyze any use of pointers, though. Sometimes, you can use C#'s `out` or `ref` instead of a pointer - go for that. But the case you have here isn't quite like that - it's a pointer stored in another type, not just passed as an argument. However, that still doesn't tell us much about how this is supposed to work in practice - maybe it's just a way to work around Pascal's limitations; maybe you'd use `List<xActor>` in C# instead of `array of PxActor`.

Of course, that's usually the best option. Where possible, use idiomatic C#, instead of just trying to code Pascal in C#. While there are many similarities, there's also a large amount of differences that can bite you, and make your work much harder than necessary. Find the places where `List<SomeType>` is going to work better than `array of PSomeType`. Find the places where `ref` and `out` can be used instead of `PSomeType`. Find where `struct` makes sense, and where `class` would be better. This applies to many subtle differences that can ruin your day, so you'll probably be finding many issues over time, but it's a journey :)

Comment: Thanks such a great explaination.